# Get tag posts wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags

I've written some code which automatically creates some posts and adds a tag to them. I can see the tags in the 'All posts' admin panel and I can click on the posts 'Tag' link to get just those posts with the tags.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $tag_ID= single_tag_title();
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'tag_id'    =>  $tag_ID,
                        'posts_per_page' => 10,
                        'order'          =>'ASC'
                    );
                    $posts = get_posts( $args );
                    var_dump($args );
                    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                        ?>
```

Can you help me to get all tag posts?
Thank you.

Comment: [get_the_tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file (**tag.php**) in `wp-content/themes/yourthemefolder/`
and put below code in it.

```
<?php
get_header();

$tag = single_tag_title('', false);
echo '<h1>Tag: ' . $tag . '</h1>';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'taxonomy' => $tag,
    'terms' => $tag,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$postslist = get_posts($args);

foreach ($postslist as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <div id="post">
        <h2>Post title:<?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; 
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: @HayAna where are you putting this code ? what is the url and what file is working ?

Comment: yes, my web page url is like you mentioned, my file is tag.php

Comment: it seems, I've done mistakes, Sorry, I clear all and write your code.
Thank you it is working fine .

Comment: your code is uploading the all categories and the tags. But I want to get only tags with one language.

Comment: are you using multilingual ?

Comment: yes I use. And the code brings out all tags in all languages

Comment: you did not mentioned in the question btw you need to add  `'suppress_filters' => false,` in `$args` array so it will filter the tags in current language.